# ¿como puedo combinar filas un 2 columnas iguales en python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Buenas tengo un dataframe tal que así;

```
cod     nombre      telefono1     telefono2
a1      pepe        65222         null
a2      juan        5454          54545
a3      pepe        65565         6464
a1      pepe        null          787887
```

Lo que necesito es combinar aquellas filas cuyo cod y nombre son iguales para que el resto de campos (telefo1,telefono2) se unieran, tal que asi

```
a1    pepe       65222         787887
```

y solo me aparezca ese registro

Gracias!

Comment: En el ejemplo que pones la unión de las filas no plantea problema porque las dos filas en cuestión tienen "null" donde la otra tiene un teléfono. ¿Qué habría de suceder si ambas tienen teléfono?

Comment: Muy buena pregunta, lo ideal es si son idénticos eliminar uno, sino concatenar ambos con una , de separación. llegado el caso que se eliminara uno de los dos seria el menor inconveniente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurre la siguiente solución. Se trata de hacer uso de `groupby()` para agrupar por `["cod", "nombre"]` (lo que deja juntas en un sub-dataframe todas las filas con el mismo cod y nombre), y después procesar cada uno de los sub-dataframes resultantes mediante `.apply()` y una función que habría que escribir.

El cometido de la función esa sería recibir un sub-dataframe en el que ya sabemos que todos los "cod", "nombre" son iguales, y por tanto debemos centrarnos solo en "condensar" en un solo valor todos los teléfonos que haya bajo la columna `"telefono1"` y `"telefono2"`, para retornar como resultado un mini-dataframe de una sola fila, con estas columnas y un solo valor en cada una.

La "condensación" de varios teléfonos en la misma columna en una sola cadena puede hacerse así:

- Se aplica `dropna()` a la columna para eliminar los null (o `NaN`)
- Se aplica `set()` sobre el resultado para eliminar duplicados
- Se crea una lista iterando sobre ese conjunto, convirtiendo cada valor en cadena (podemos usar la cadena de formato `"{:g}"` para que no contenga decimales, ya que un número de teléfono no tiene decimales, pero en cambio Pandas lo estará tratando como `float` debido a la existencia de `NaN` en la columna.
- Se juntan los elementos de la lista mediante `", ".join()` para que queden separados por comas.

Todo lo anterior parece muy largo, pero se resuelve en una sola línea (y otra idéntica para la otra columna "telefono2"). Una vez tenemos ambos resultados retornamos el dataframe que los contenga.

Así pues ésta sería la función:

```
def juntar_telefonos(df):
  t1 = ", ".join(f"{tfno:g}" for tfno in set(df.telefono1.dropna()))
  t2 = ", ".join(f"{tfno:g}" for tfno in set(df.telefono2.dropna()))
  return pd.DataFrame({"telefono1": [t1], "telefono2": [t2]})
```

Y para aplicarla en combinación con el `groupby()` sería así:

```
df.groupby(["cod", "nombre"]).apply(juntar_telefonos).droplevel(-1).reset_index()
```

El `.droplevel()` del final es para eliminar un índice extra que sería añadido por el dataframe que `juntar_telefonos()` está retornando, y el `reset_index()` es para que las antiguas columnas "cod" y "nombre", que debido al `groupby()` se habían convertido en índices, vuelvan a ser columnas normales.

### Ejemplos

Probamos sobre tu dataframe:

```
  cod nombre  telefono1  telefono2
0  a1   pepe    65222.0        NaN
1  a2   juan     5454.0    54545.0
2  a3   pepe    65565.0     6464.0
3  a1   pepe        NaN   787887.0
```

y sale:

```
  cod nombre telefono1 telefono2
0  a1   pepe     65222    787887
1  a2   juan      5454     54545
2  a3   pepe     65565      6464
```

Probemos con un dataframe que tenga varios teléfonos en una columna (telefono2)

```
  cod nombre  telefono1  telefono2
0  a1   pepe    65222.0       1234
1  a2   juan     5454.0      54545
2  a3   pepe    65565.0       6464
3  a1   pepe        NaN     787887
```

Aquí el resultado es:

```
  cod nombre telefono1     telefono2
0  a1   pepe     65222  1234, 787887
1  a2   juan      5454         54545
2  a3   pepe     65565          6464
```

Finalmente un caso en el que la columna (telefono1) tiene null en todas las entradas de ese usuario:

```
  cod nombre  telefono1  telefono2
0  a1   pepe        NaN        NaN
1  a2   juan     5454.0    54545.0
2  a3   pepe    65565.0     6464.0
3  a1   pepe        NaN   787887.0
```

Resultado:

```
  cod nombre telefono1 telefono2
0  a1   pepe              787887
1  a2   juan      5454     54545
2  a3   pepe     65565      6464
```

Parece que funciona bien en todos los casos.

Comment: Muy bueno!!! mil gracias :)